# Vue load component from Laravel view

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I'm new in Vue and Laravel and I'm doing testing about these frameworks.

I would like to load a Vue Component with an array. The idea is to past to Laravel view by Prop parameter of the Vue Component. **I'm not sure that this is the correct way** or is a better option to get the values use axios directly from the Vue Component.

At the moment I'm trying to load from array Prop paramenter into the component.

The code of the Vue component is:

```
<template>
  <div>
      <b-form-select
        v-model="selected"
        :options="ar"
        class="mb-3"
        value-field="customer_name">
      </b-form-select>     
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
        props: ['customers'],

        data: function() {
          return {
            ar: JSON.parse(this.customers)
          }
        }
    }
</script>
```

UPDATE

create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section ('botones')
@endsection
@section('content')
    <h2 class="text-center mb-5"> Add Task</h2>
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">      
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('taskjobs.store') }}" novalidate> 
                @csrf
                <div class="form-group">
                  
                <form-task :customers="json_encode($customers)"></form-task> // interpolation is not necessary
               
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-dark" value="Add Task">
    
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>     
    </div>
    
@endsection
```

TaskJobController.php

```
   /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
        $customers = Customer::all(['id', 'customer_name']);
        $jobs= Job::all(['id', 'job_name']);
        $concepts= Concept::all(['id', 'concept_name']);
        return view('taskjobs.create')
        ->with('customers', $customers)
        ->with('jobs', $jobs)
        ->with('concepts', $concepts);
    }
```

Now the form element show a null values but in the ul the elements show fine as a json object. It's very confused for me.

Maybe somebody can help me... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Iam not sure about laravel View but in general if are passing a props to a vue component, you need to use bind operator ':' (ie)

Try doing

```
<form-task :customers="@json($customers)"></form-task>
```

OR

```
<form-task :customers="{!! json_encode($customers) !!}"></form-task>
```

Try defining ar as a computed property like below

```
The code of the Vue component is:

<template>
  <div>
      <b-form-select
        v-model="selected"
        :options="ar"
        class="mb-3"
        value-field="customer_name">
      </b-form-select>     
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
        props: ['customers'],
        computed: {
          ar: {
            return JSON.parse(this.customers);
         }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Vue warn]: Property or method "json_encode" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

Comment: without interpolation the method json_encode not works

Comment: Can you share the full code of laravel view?

Comment: I have updated the post with the view and controller code.

Comment: Please check my updated answer and see if its works

Comment: Show this in the browser:":1,"customer_name":"customer1"},{"id":2,"customer_name":"customer2"}]"="">

Comment: It doesn't show the form select element only the json

Comment: b-form-select required options to be of a particular format
Please check this: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-select

Comment: Below <b-form-select>, you have div with li tags right...thats what is getting displayed

Comment: Below <b-form-select> only it's for a testing. I have deleted from post. I have read the documentation of the component hours ago ;) I don't know why show the array the component with a text and not with an elements.

Comment: Check my updated answer and see if it works